# Placement of absolutely positioned elements incorrect when printing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

I am currently facing a strange problem (well, most probably I am simply not aware of something important here).

I have the following html snippet

```
<div id="test">
  Hallo Welt
</div>
```

And the following javascript snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('#test').offset({
      position: 'absolute',
      width: '100px',  
      left: ($('body').width() - $('#test').width()) / 2.0
    })
  });
</script>
```

This should render the test div horizontally centered which works perfectly fine within the browser. When I try to print this page however, the element shows up on the right corner of the printed page and not in the middle.

I thought maybe theres something wrong about using pixels for positioning elements for printing so I tried other measures like em:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('body, #test').css({ 'font-size': '12px' });

    $('#test').css({
      left: (($('body').width() - $('#test').width() ) / 24.0) + 'em'
    })
  });
</script>
```

But unfortunately the result is all the same, no matter what browser I try...
What am I missing here?

#

In response to Adrian I made a sample as simple as possible to extract the problem reproducable for everyone.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        $('#test').css({
          background:'red',
          position: 'absolute',
          width: '100px',
          left: ($('body').width() - 100) / 2.0
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="test">
      Lord
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I also observed that the position of #test within the printed document is dependant on the size of the browser window at the time of printing.

Comment: Is it possible you have a `@media print` query in your css causing it to do something else?

Comment: @Adrian I complemented my question with a standalone sample you can try on your compuer ;-)

Comment: I realized that $('#some-div').width() returns the size of the width of the div within the browser instead the width within of the printing page. Thats where the problem starts. Is there a way to query the "canvas" or whatever width which returns the width of the div in the browser OR in the printing page when being printed?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Newer Solution with js only...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        $('#test').css({
          background:'red',
          position: 'absolute',
          width: '100px',
          left: '50%',
          marginLeft: '-50px'
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="test">
      Lord
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

CSS solution

In this situation I would use CSS `@media print {}` to target printing.

Im assuming you have a reason for using javascript to build your CSS but if not I would recommend coding this in a totally different way. This shouldnt require javascript, nor should it require an absolute position.

Anyway , solution below...

```
<html>
  <head>
  <style>

  @media print {

    #test {
        left:50% !important;
        margin-left:-50px;
    }

  }
  </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        $('#test').css({
          background:'red',
          position: 'absolute',
          width: '100px',
          left: ($('body').width() - 100) / 2.0
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="test">
      Lord
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am developing a complex scheduler component and I need to position the events within the scheduler with javascript. The problem ist that while looking good on the screen, the same events are floating around everywhere when trying to print the very same scheduler which looks good on the screen.

Comment: ah ok, ill edit my post with a more suitable solution

Answer (score 0):

I am actually working with media queries as well in my real project. I was trying to convey an extremely simply sample as a showcase for the problem.

This is also interesting and the root of the evil in my opinion. Even though the printer uses its 100px from the print media query, its executed javascript returns that the test div ist still 100% which is just wrong in my opinion!!!

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        $('#test').text($('#test').width());
      });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
      #test {
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }

      @media print {
        #test {
          width: 100px;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="test"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```